# keytool for Android debug key giving garbage value

Tags: android, keytool

I am using macbook 
I typed below code on terminal

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

and end up with

0???|???*?H??
071
   0    UUS10U
450329083337Z071
                0   UUS10U
?0?roid *?H??0?"0
??&{??@u???_??R??M?C?   ?ߔ?"??V?L??????X=y???P9,????gq?v-b|?x??W5WR?r??*?
?c+W??NWS!P??????ʈl??SO?̡E??]???wO???OhMⳳӾ?៎m???et???A?K?8 ]?#??,?l??'N8??WZ?*x폻(??҄-y??J?*?H??]???mD,???>?3?Ð?=ߌh??ib???????p6\??????!00U????W? ?p8`+??P?b??0
?rGNh?o(5*?<????x????b??7;1?ƻ?H?L1?>?O~&?O??E??Ӎ?5c?62?? ~?????ܙKv=?E???U?d?`.?̶?}?U??ѭ?Q0????G??Jʀ?֯r?????
                                    =g?P??n??s?S?3?\o????kO?_u???9??iv?????5A҈?)9?-??nO?~@Pq?x  ???
                   ???-?b(???\?P?xd?Ԩ?#8z8b>SG?z?f??????%?

What is the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have missed last two word -list -v

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

its working now